# Using jQuery datepicker with multiple django forms in one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, datepicker, django-widget

So I have a create announcement form and then an edit form for each announcement and each form has its own datepicker.  My function for controlling the datepicker is:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
    });
});
```

Initially my issue was that using the datepicker in one of the edit forms would change the field in the create form since the ids were the same.  I got around this by adding ids (in my `forms.py`) like so:

```
end_date = forms.DateField(label='Expires', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker form-control', 'id':'end_date_create'}))
```

and

```
end_date = forms.DateField(label='Expires', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker form-control', 'id':'end_date_edit'}))
```

to my createAnnouncement and EditAnnouncement forms.  But since I have multiple edit forms per page, I still have the same issue where using the datepicker on any edit form changes the field of only the top edit form.  I am using django widget tweaks to render my forms so it automatically generates HTML and ids and classes and everything.  Each edit form is in a div with a unique id, but the form fields themselves are named the same thing across all the forms.  Does anyone know how I could generate unique ids for my form fields with django widget tweaks?  Or maybe there is some javascript or something I could add to my datepicker function that tells the datepicker to change the value of the field that is in the same div?

EDIT: My template looks like this:

```
{% if boardAnnouncements %}
<h3>Announcements</h3>
    <div class="container" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
        <ul>
            {% for announcement in boardAnnouncements %}
                <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                <li>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <!-- display announcement content -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <!-- edit button calls javascript function to hide/unhide div with edit form in it -->
                        <a href="javascript:unhide_announcement('editann-{{announcement.id}}', '{{announcement.id}}')" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 10px;"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- each div gets unique id that corresponds to announcemt id -->
                <div id="editann-{{announcement.id}}" class="hidden">
                    <form role="form" action="/editannouncement/{{announcement.id}}/" method="post">
                            <!-- display edit form with django widget tweaks -->
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {% for field in editAnnouncement %}
                                {% if field.errors %}
                                    <div class="form-group has-error">
                                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="id_{{ field.name }}">
                                        {{ field.label }}</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            {{ field }}
                                            <span class="help-block">
                                            {% for error in  field.errors %}
                                                {{ error }}
                                            {% endfor %}
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                {% else %}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="id_{{ field.name }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            {{ field }}
                                            {% if field.help_text %}
                                                <p class="help-block"><small>{{ field.help_text }}</small></p>
                                            {% endif %}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                        <button type="submit" name="edit_announcement" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button><br><br>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                </li>
                </div>
            {% endfor %} 
        </ul>
    </div>  
    {% endif %}
<div>
```

And the generated HTML for the edit forms is:

```
<div id="editann-1" class="unhidden">
    <form class="ng-pristine ng-valid" role="form" action="/editannouncement/1/" method="post">
        <input name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="AbTEZYmK1RF9yeom1C34IFFCj3EBrOD3" type="hidden">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="id_description">Edit Description</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea class="form-control" cols="40" id="id_description" name="description" rows="10"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="id_end_date">Expires</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input class="datepicker form-control hasDatepicker" id="end_date_edit" name="end_date" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit" name="edit_announcement" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button><br><br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="editann-2" class="unhidden">
    <form class="ng-pristine ng-valid" role="form" action="/editannouncement/2/" method="post">
        <input name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="AbTEZYmK1RF9yeom1C34IFFCj3EBrOD3" type="hidden">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="id_description">Edit Description</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea class="form-control" cols="40" id="id_description" name="description" rows="10"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="id_end_date">Expires</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input class="datepicker form-control hasDatepicker" id="end_date_edit" name="end_date" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit" name="edit_announcement" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button><br><br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

So to clarify each editann-# div has an edit form in it (and each edit form has a datepicker).  Right now since the all the edit form "Expire" fields have id `id_end_date` the datepicker changes the value of the first edit form, no matter which datepicker I am using.

Comment: what is the exact problem? Show your rendered html and the parts of the form you want the datepicker js to be applied to and those you do not want it to be applied to.

Comment: @YPCrumble I've added my template code and generated HTML, does that help clarify the issue?

Comment: what is the desired result? You want the second "Expires" field to become a datepicker but not the first one? Or something else? Sorry still having trouble understanding what the actual issue is.

Comment: No so each form when I click the text input area the datepicker shows up (which is what I want), but then when I select a date my datepicker function fills in the value of the first edit form. Say I have 3 announcements on my page and I want to edit the expiration date of the third one.  I click the edit button, the edit announcement div gets unhidden, I put my cursor in the expires field and the datepicker appears, I chose a date but then that date appears in the edit form of the first announcement, not the third.  So I need a way to associate each datepicker with the correct form @YPCrumble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution involving some javascript and jQuery.

```
function unhide_announcement(divID, ID) {
var item = document.getElementById(divID);
if (item) {
    /* hide/unhide div */
    item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden';
    /* give each end_date field a unique ID */
    var newID = 'id_end_date' + ID;
    item.querySelector('#id_end_date').id = newID;
    /* datepicker functionality */
    $(function() {                                                    
        $( '#'+newID ).datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
        });
      })
    }
}
```

Since each edit announcement form is in a unique div, I get that div first and then within the div there is only 1 edit announcement form so I change that id from `id_end_date` to `id_end_date1` or whichever announcement id it is associated with.  And then I changed the jQuery datepicker function I had to select by id instead of by class and it worked.  So when I call it in my template it looks like this:

```
<a href="javascript:unhide_announcement('editann-{{announcement.id}}', '{{announcement.id}}')" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
<div id="editann-{{announcement.id}}" class="hidden">
    <!-- edit announcement form -->
    <form>
        ...
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have two of the same `id` on one page. [ID's must be unique](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id). That's what is creating the error.

To add more than one form on the page, you should use [Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/#module-django.forms.formsets) which will automatically make sure your id's are unique.

By removing the `id` attribute from your code I was able to make the datepickers work. See [this working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ypcrumble/tsesoksk/5/).

Note that I had to remove `hasDatepicker` class from the html you pasted as that's actually inserted by the `datepicker` function - if you leave it in it will create a conflict and the datepicker won't show up.

Comment: I know that ids need to be unique, but django widget tweaks automatically generates the HTML (including the ids).  That's why I was asking if anyone knows how to generate unique ones with widget tweaks.  I am displaying announcements in a for loop so it does the exact same thing for each announcement

Comment: @Catherine since you have two loops here you can use `forloop.counter` with `parentloop.counter` to make the ids unique.

Comment: this sounds helpful but I am having trouble implementing it in my template, I tried replacing `{{ field }}` with `{{ field|attr:"id:end_date_edit-{{forloop.parentloop.counter}}" }}` but it gives me an error TemplateSyntaxError: attr requires 2 arguments, 1 provided.  Your suggestion just changes the label for id, not the actual id of the form field

Comment: @Catherine sorry - you should be using a Formset - that will make sure the id's are unique for you.

Comment: I ended up writing some javascript that takes the divID and announcement ID as parameters and changes the expire form field id from "id_end_date" to "id_end_date" + ID but now when I try to use the datepicker I get error "Missing instance data for this datepicker" so do you know how I could change my datepicker function to handle ids instead of classes?  I don't really have any experience with jQuery, I copied the function so I'm not sure how to change it